# General methods for proving countability and uncountability

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to get a broad intuition for which methods exist for proving that a set $S$ is either countable or uncountable. This is my intuition based on what I have seen so far in Baby Rudin:

It seems that, to prove that $S$ is countable, one must either

1. Find a function $f : S \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ and show that it is bijective (i.e., show that it is both injective and surjective), or
2. Use Theorem 2.12, which essentially states that the union of a countable collection of countable sets is countable.

The only method that I have seen used to prove that $S$ is uncountable is to

1. Show that $S$ is infinite by showing that $S$ is equivalent to one of its proper subsets.

But since a set is uncountable if and only if it is neither finite nor countable, I'm not sure how one would approach the argument from the opposite direction, by showing that $S$ is not countable.

What is an example of a situation where one might need to show that something is uncountable because it is not countable, and how would one go about proving such a claim?

Additionally, are there other general arguments for showing that something is countable?

Thanks!

Comment: Schroeder-Bernstein theorem states that if you can find an injection $f:A \rightarrow B$ and another injection $g:B \rightarrow A$, then sets must have the same cardinality.

Comment: To prove a set is uncountable, you can take your unknown set $S$, and a known uncountable set $U$ (e.g. $\Bbb{R}$, $\Bbb{N}^\Bbb{N}$, $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb{N})$, etc), and find either an injection $U \to S$, or a surjection $S \to U$.

Answer (score 1):

The most famous uncountability argument is Cantor's diagonalization, i.e. given an arbitrary enumeration $f: \mathbb{N} \to S$, you construct an element of $S$ that is not in the range of $f$ (i.e. show that it is not surjective).

Alternatively, and analogously to your point 1 for countable sets, you could find $f: S \to \mathbb{R}$ (or any other known uncountable set) and show that it is bijective (or just surjective).